# Where has Tolkien's Second Age material been published?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, j-r-r-tolkien, numenor

A new Tolkien collection, *The Fall of Númenor*, is due to be published in a few months.  It will contain all of the second age material. I believe this will all be reprints. Aside from *The Silmarillion* and *Unfinished Tales*, what other Tolkien collections contained second age material?

Comment: I've edited the title to better reflect what I think you're asking here. (As being unpublished and the contents unknown, questions specifically about the contents The Fall of Númenor would fall under our "Future Works" policy.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following existing Tolkien publications contain Second Age material, presented here in order of publication.

- **The Lord of the Rings (1955,1965)**

  - The first couple of pages of Appendix A and B, also a scattering of references in the main text.
- **The Silmarillion (1977,1999)**

  - Akallabêth
  - Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age
  - From a Letter by J.R.R. Tolkien
- **Unfinished Tales (1980)**

  - A Description Of The Island Of Númenor
  - Aldarion And Erendis: The Mariner's Wife
  - The Line Of Elros: Kings Of Númenor
  - The History Of Galadriel And Celeborn (And Appendices)
- **The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien (1981)**

  - Letters #'s: 131, 153, 156, 211 and 276
- **The Lost Road and Other Writings (1987)**

  - The Early History of the Legend
  - The Fall of Númenor
  - The Númenórean chapters
- **Sauron Defeated (1992)**

  - The Notion Club Papers (mainly just Part Two, nights 65-68)
  - The Drowning of Anadûnê
- **The Peoples of Middle-earth (1996)**

  - Of Dwarves and Men
  - Last Writings (Glorfindel II, The Five Wizards)
  - Tal-Elmar
- **La Feuille de la Compagnie, vol.3, J.R.R. Tolkien, l'effigie des Elfes (2014)**

  - The Númenórean Catastrophe & End of 'Physical' Arda
- **J.R.R. Tolkien: Maker of Middle-earth (2018)**

  - Fig. 77, Map of Númenor
- **The Nature of Middle-earth (2021)**

  - Lives of the Númenóreans
  - The Ageing of Númenóreans
  - Of the Land and Beasts of Númenor
  - The Númenórean Catastrophe & End of "Physical" Aman
  - Galadriel and Celeborn
  - Silvan Elves and Silvan Elvish
  - Note on the Delay of Gil-galad and the Númenóreans

Comment: Should mention that I'm 99% certain a ton of this will *not* be included in Brian Sibley's book. The impression that I got from his statements is that his book is intended at a much more general audience than a lot of the above publications were, and for example I really can't see him including ten different versions of the Akallabêth, or (unfortunately) probably anything from The Notion Club Papers.

Comment: And should also mention that a few of these are dupes. The Letter used in the preface to the 2nd Edition Silm can be found as #131 in Letters, and the stuff from that French journal can be found in NoMe. (There's also some overlap between NoMe and UT, but in this case the writings are presented in a way that you'd wish there was more overlap, so that you don't need to constantly flip back and forth books every other paragraph.)